# Dose exists() in r help find a factor

Tags: r

```
class(wnd$ORIGIN)
[1] "factor"
```

Within the variable ORIGIN, there exists a level SFO.
Can I use exists(), to find out if it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exists()` is used to find whether an object exists in an environment. You want to know about the levels of a factor object. So no, `exists()` is not the right function for this task. The levels of a factor are not R objects.

It is best to use `levels()`, like this

```
"SFO" %in% levels(wnd$ORIGIN)
```

or

```
any(levels(wnd$ORIGIN) == "SFO")
```

This will give `TRUE` if `SFO` is a level, and `FALSE` otherwise.